# How to replace more than one common sub string in a single string with another string?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos

```
    for(int i= 0 ;i<[urlsArrray count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *urlString = [urlsArrray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *escapedUrlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];

        NSString *urlstring1 = [url absoluteString];
        NSArray *parts = [urlstring1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSString *fileName = [parts objectAtIndex:[parts count]-1];

        NSMutableString *tempString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:fileName];

       // [tempString replaceCharactersInRange:[tempString rangeOfString:@"%20"] withString:@" "];

                NSLog(@"file name in temp string: %@ word name: %@", tempString, wordNameDB);

                NSRange match = [tempString rangeOfString:wordNameDB];
                if(match.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    NSLog(@"match found at %u", match.location);
                    isAvailable = YES;
                    break;
                }
```

Hi friends, now my problem is i am getting file name from server..., if file name is having any spaces then it replace '%20'  ( i.e ex: "hello world" is actual name but i am getting file name like: "hello%20world") .
1. I am not sure all file names having spaces.
2. And also i am not sure a file may have only one space

so first i have to check the file is having spaces or not, if have then i want to replace all "%20" with @" " string. Please give me any suggestions or code snippets.

OR " THERE IA ANY OTHER WAY TO READ FILE NAMES WITHOUT GETTING '%20' IN THE PLACE OF SPACE(@" ")..... thank you

Comment: Space isn't the only character that will be encoded (this is URL encoding BTW) in this way...

Comment: Your code has a bunch of issues that will produce all kinds of subtle bugs. Un-escaping the string is not the only problem. It would be best to just get rid of all the URL parsing, un-escaping and string replacing. Since NSURL is made to refer to files, of course there's a very easy solution in the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is replacing the escape charcters, according to the encoding. 
Use this and all your spaces and other URL encoded characters will be converted to what you need.

```
[@"yourString" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your file name stored in `fileName` param, you can use the following:

```
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
```

The above code will replace all `"%20"` with `" "`. If there are no `"%20"` in the `fileName`, you will get back the same string.

**Correction:**
I was confused with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` mentioned in code and thought you have already used `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`. If you are not using `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method, you should use that in this case. The above code is useful, only if that is not able to remove any particular string which you want to replace.

Comment: My answer was posted based on the impression that he is already using that. But later I found out that it is `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` and not `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`. Anyways reverted.

Comment: Yes I made the same mistake.

Comment: @user2086869, If @Vlad's answer worked for you, you can accept that answer since he posted first with `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

Answer (score 1):

> THERE IA ANY OTHER WAY TO READ FILE NAMES WITHOUT GETTING '%20' IN THE PLACE OF SPACE(@" ")

Yes, use this:

```
NSString *newString = [yourstring stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to remove spaces ..

urlString = [urlString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet  whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 0):

You seem to already have a valid `NSURL` object representing the file. Getting the filename from a URL is easy:

```
...
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
NSString *path = [url path];
NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];
```

No fiddling with unescaping percent escapes, URL parsing, and other error prone stuff.